# Regex To Match A Pipe-Delineated File

Tags: java, regex

I need help with a regex to check if a line matches a line of pipe delineated data. The data will end with a pipe, and is not quoted. Some fields will be empty.

Here's what I'm trying to use:

```
Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\|^");
```

Here is a sample line of data:

```
GJ 3486|||121.10766667|-83.23302778|295.84892861999998|-24.832649669999999||-0.48399999999999999||.371|2MASS J08042586-8313589|8.9700000000000006|8.3539999999999992|8.1110000000000007||2MASS||
```

Since I only wanted to see if the line matched the pattern, I thought the one I came up with would look for "blah blah blah |". Apparently not... can anyone help me out?

Jason

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
^(.*?\|)*$
```

Try this instead.

```
"
^        # Assert position at the beginning of the string
(        # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .        # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *?       # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
   \\|       # Match the character “|” literally
)*       # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\$        # Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
"
```

Some problems with your regex :

- Fist it is not repeating, you should repeat the pattern since you have many columns.
- You match something and then you match tne start of the string. Not possible, this will never match.
- You always want a character to match but you said there could be empty columns. Instead use * quantifier.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to escape `$`
What does `*?` mean? I know `?` or `*` but i don't understand why there is an `*?` in your regex

Comment: The escape is just for the explanation. .*? Is lazy quantifier so that it does not consume |.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for the help... my regex-fu is weak.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong it should be:

```
Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)\\|$");
```

Comment: This is also wrong. You don't take care of empty columns and you don't take care of repetitions.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
str.length() > 1 && str.charAt(str.length()-1) == '|'
```

Is probably much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile("^([^\\|]*\\|)+$");
```

This regex should work. But if you just want to check if your line ends with a pipe this regex is more simple:

```
Pattern dataPattern = Pattern.compile("^.*\\|$");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using `^` at the end of the line, but you should be using `$` instead.

`"(.+)\\|$"`